# Изменить фон div при наведении на другой

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такой код:

```html
<div class="div1">
 <div class="div11">Текст</div>
</div>

<div class="div2">
 <div class="div12">Текст</div>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на .div11 менялся фон div12. Верстку нельзя менять.

Comment: какие технологии допустимы для решения задачи? `css` / `js` / ... ? указание только тега `html` в вопросе не даёт этого понять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var div11 = document.querySelector('.div11');
var div12 = document.querySelector('.div12');

div11.addEventListener('mouseover', handle);
div11.addEventListener('mouseleave', handle2);

function handle() {
  div12.style.background = 'lightgreen';
}

function handle2() {
  div12.style.background = '';
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
 <div class="div11">Текст</div>
</div>

<div class="div2">
 <div class="div12">Текст</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Ваш ответ больше всего подходит. Таких div-ов порядка 20-30 штук. и все с разными классами.

Answer (score 0):

Никак, если использовать только CSS - CSS правила действуют каскадно.
Можно лишь через наведение на `.div1`, т.к. он на одном уровне с `.div2`.

Если через использование скриптов, то, например, вот так:

```js
$('.div11').hover(
  function() {
    $('.div12').css('background', 'green')
  },
  function() {
    $('.div12').css('background', 'transparent')
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
 <div class="div11">Текст</div>
</div>

<div class="div2">
 <div class="div12">Текст</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Даже если строк куда больше (и без JavaScript):

```css
div[class^="div"]:hover + div[class^="div"] > div {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div11">Текст</div>
</div>

<div class="div2">
  <div class="div12">Текст</div>
</div>

<div class="div3">
  <div class="div13">Текст</div>
</div>

<div class="div4">
  <div class="div14">Текст</div>
</div>

<div class="div5">
  <div class="div15">Текст</div>
</div>

<div class="div6">
  <div class="div16">Текст</div>
</div>
```

Comment: автор указал, что разметку менять нельзя. так что ответ не соответствует вопросу, к сожалению: в первом случае окрашивается не внутренний, а внешний `div`, а во втором случае изменён класс родителей.

Comment: @lexxl а так? :)

Comment: и так. где тут `<div class="div1">`? запрет на изменение разметки означает, скорее всего, что это уже работающий проект, и изменения могут повлечь за собой череду других нежелательных переделок. а классы даны в примере, наверняка, условно

Comment: @lexxl боже ж ты мой... Поправил. Только не надо говорить, что в вопросе не было div'ов с классами 3-6. Они добавлены для наглядности.

Comment: не в этом дело) если я прав, и классы даны для наглядности, то этот  вопрос можно перефразировать вот так: <div class="father">
 <div class="boy">Текст</div>
</div> и <div class="mother">
 <div class="girl">Текст</div>
</div>

Comment: @lexxl а я не думаю. Вопрос поставлен достаточно конкретно (хотя вы верно в комментарии к нему подметили, что не указан инструмент решения, но не об этом речь). При наведении на `div11` изменить `div12`. При наведении на `div15` изменить `div16`.

Comment: Прежде чем умничать и утверждать, что это возможно решить без js, перепишите Ваш css адекватно!!!

Это сработает если писать условие так (Ваше условие в нормальном виде): `.div1:hover~.div2 .div12 {
  background: tomato;
}`, НО НЕ ТАК (этот код не сработает): `.div11:hover~.div2 .div12 {
  background: tomato;
}`